# Toolbar fragment back click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in my fragment.

Also I declared in my Fragment `onViewCreated` this:

```
        ((MainActivity) mCtx).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((MainActivity) mCtx).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        ((MainActivity) mCtx).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But I cant make that Toolbar button back to work no way.

How to do that?

Tried to:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackAction();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens app exit or back button not working?

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar button not workign, just gives "ripple effect".
Don't even enter `onOptionsItemSelected` as I am debuggin.

Comment: try to use this way ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

Comment: Where are you overriding `onOptionsItemSelected(...)`? `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Comment: On the `Fragment` `onCreate` call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onBackAction();` use:

```
onBackPressed();
break;
```